# CAST data to correct datatype, if failes insert into table

Tags: mysql

I have lots of bad data. I can easily import this data to database and use datatype varchar.
However, if I want CAST data to correct format I have problems, because of bad data.

Because I have to fix this data, I need to take rows what I can CAST correct format and put those rows "fixed"-table and those rows what fails to CAST I have to insert into "failed"-table.

I think that best way to do this is using stored procedure, but can someone show me example how to do this?
Im using MySQL database.

Comment: You can probably do this without resorting to a stored proc.  Can you include some sample which both explains your problem and covers most of the edge cases?

Answer (score 0):

Untested!  I'll try to insert VARCHAR into INT column.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_article_tags_2(IN data VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE  has_error INT;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET has_error = 1;

 INSERT INTO mytable (id)
   VALUES(data);

 IF has_error = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO mytable_error (rawdata) VALUES(data);
 END IF;

END;
$$
```